# Why doesn't `java.util.List.contains()` return true when I match the string?

Tags: java, algorithm

Why when I use the method `contains()` in a Java `List` it doesn't return true when I match the string?

I'm doing an exercise in HackerEarth and I can't pass a test.
This is the text of exercise:

> Arpasland has surrounded by attackers. A truck enters the city. The
> driver claims the load is food and medicine from Iranians. Ali is one
> of the soldiers in Arpasland. He doubts about the truck, maybe it's
> from the siege. He knows that a tag is valid if the sum of every two
> consecutive digits of it is even and its letter is not a vowel.
> Determine if the tag of the truck is valid or not.
>
> We consider the letters "A","E","I","O","U","Y" to be vowels for this
> problem.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains a string of length 9. The format is
> "DDXDDD-DD", where D stands for a digit (non zero) and X is an
> uppercase English letter.
>
> Output Format
>
> Print "valid" (without quotes) if the tag is valid, print "invalid"
> otherwise (without quotes).

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
                
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sum = 0;

        boolean flagIsNotVowel = false;
        boolean flagIsEven = false;
        String word = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(word);
         
        List<String> dic = new ArrayList();
         dic.add("A");
         dic.add("E");
         dic.add("I");
         dic.add("O");
         dic.add("U");
         dic.add("Y");
        System.out.println()

        for(int i =0;i<word.length();i++){
            boolean flag = Character.isDigit(word.charAt(i));
           
            if(flag) {
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(word.charAt(i)+ "");
                flagIsEven  = sum%2==0 ? true : false;
            }
            if(!flag && !dic.contains(word.charAt(i) ){
                 System.out.println(word.charAt(i) +"letter");
                 System.out.println(dic.contains(word.charAt(i)) + "true");
                sum = 0;
                flagIsNotVowel = true;
            } 

            if(!flag && dic.contains(word.charAt(i))){
                 System.out.println(word.charAt(i)+ "ciao da dic");
                sum = 0;
                flagIsNotVowel = false;
            }
        }
      
        if(flagIsEven ==true  &&  flagIsNotVowel == true){
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

This is one test that I can't pass  : 13A357-22

Comment: You're printing the input and empty lines. Neither are `valid` or `invalid`, which are the only outputs that HackerRank will allow

Comment: Yes I know but this is not the problem the real problem is in the contains method

Comment: code is hard to read - too many empty lines - comments without meaning || ONE problem, as far as I could *find*: `charAt()` returns a `char` - this will never be `equals` a `String` (stored in list)

Comment: `List<String>` will never contain a `Character` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is allowed to use regular expressions for this task, the following solution may be suggested (somewhat similar to [that of @Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71272964/13279831)) with some changes:

1. validate the format of the tag to be `DDXDDD-DD`, where `D` is a non-zero digit, `X` is a consonant
   This can be done using a positive lookahead:
   `(?=[1-9]{2}[B-Z&&[^EIOUY]][1-9]{3}-[1-9]{2})`
   where `[B-Z&&[^EIOUY]]` is a range of capital letters `B-Z` *except for* vowels `[^EIOUY]` (`A` is excluded)
2. check the pairs of digit NOT to contain mix of odd and even digits:

```java
public static String isValid(String str) {
    return str.matches("(?=[1-9]{2}[B-Z&&[^EIOUY]][1-9]{3}-[1-9]{2})((?!.*(?:[2468][13579]|[13579][2468]))\\d{2,3}[-B-Z&&[^EIOUY]]?){3}")
        ? "valid"
        : "invalid";
}
```

---

Checking for the sum of two consecutive digits to be even may be implemented as follows:

```java
public static String isValid(String str) {
    boolean hasValidFormat = str.matches("\\[1-9]][B-Z&&[^EIOUY]][1-9]{3}-[1-9]{2}");
    if (hasValidFormat) {
        out: for (String part : str.split("\\D")) {
            int firstDigit = Character.getNumericValue(part.charAt(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < part.length(); i++) {
                int digit = Character.getNumericValue(part.charAt(i));
                if ((digit + firstDigit) % 2 != 0) {
                    hasValidFormat = false;
                    break out;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hasValidFormat ? "valid" : "invalid";
}
```

Tests:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("13A357-22", "22X468-19", "222F444K555");
for (String test : data) {
    System.out.println(test + " " + isValid(test));
}
```

Output:

```
13A357-22 invalid
22X468-19 valid
222F444K555 invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that test is that the letter is a vowel. Your code, when dealing with the `A` character, correctly sets  `flagIsNotVowel` to `false`.

However, later you deal with the `-` character no different than any other non-digit character. `-` is not a vowel, so your code now sets `flagIsNotVowel` to true.

You need to do absolutely nothing when the character is a dash; if the dash causes you to set `flagIsNotVowel` to anything, your code will not be correct anymore.

Note that `continue;` will end processing of the loop and immediately skip to the next iteration. This may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the tag is comprised of nine characters, the third being a capital letter, the seventh being a hyphen and the remaining seven all being non-zero digits.

The tag is valid if and only if it matches the following regular expression:

```
^(?!.*(?:[2468][13579]|[13579][2468]))[1-9]{2}[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ][1-9]{3}-[1-9]{2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d22a8q/1)

Observe that the sum of two non-zero digits is even if and only both digits are even or both digits are odd.

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                    # match the beginning of the string
(?!                  # begin a negative lookahead 
  .*                 # match zero or more characters
  (?:                # begin a non-capture group
    [2468][13579]    # match an non-zero digit followed by an odd digit
    |                # or
    [13579][2468]    # match an odd digit followed by a non-zero even digit
  )                  # end non-capture group
)                    # end the negative lookahead
[1-9]{2}             # match two digits
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]   # match a capital letter that is a consonant
[1-9]{3}             # match three digits
-                    # match a hyphen
[1-9]{2}             # match two digits
$                    # match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way. It passes all the testcase :)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String word = br.readLine();
        String output = "valid";
        String [] vowel = {"A","E","I","O","U","Y"}; 

         for(int i =0;i<word.length()-1;i++){
             if(Character.isDigit(word.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(word.charAt(i+1))) {
                 int sum = Integer.parseInt(word.charAt(i)+ "") + Integer.parseInt(word.charAt(i+1)+ "");
                 if(sum%2!=0){
                     output = "invalid";
                     break;
                 } continue;
           } else if((Arrays.asList(vowel).contains(word.charAt(i)+""))){
               output = "invalid";
                     break;
           }
           continue;           
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks accepting "", "A13357-22", "222F444K555" and whatnot.